# Ubuntu Hotspot - Need IP range same as other LAN devices

Tags: 14.04, wireless, hot-spot

There are multiple ubuntu systems connected in LAN. All have IP range 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.4 etc

When any system starts a hotspot service, it starts successfully and smart phone devices can be connected successfully so any hotspot.

But their IP range is 10.42.0.2, 10.42.0.8, 10.42.0.23 etc

I need to create them same as LAN IP range i.e. 192.168.0.x

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to check on device that is responsible for hotspot network.

The question is not related to Ubuntu itself: You have 2 LAN segments 192.168.0.X and 10.32.0.X that are controlled by some network hardware running DHCP server software on it.

It might be one device or tow depending on the topology of your network.

As so we are here of no help as we can't guess the device models and other data needed from your question.